# Mysql not connecting with domain name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
*mysql -h mysql_servername -u username -p 
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'10.2.3.2' (using password: YES)*
```

whet is needed :

*mysql -h mysql_servername -u username -p 
    Enter password:
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'mysql_servername' (using password: YES)*
Not sure why mysql_servername  is getting converted to respective ip.

How to tell mysql no to lookout for dns binding?

I want to connect it via hostname itself (check in /etc/hosts and DNS that conversion for ip is not there.Thanks

Comment: You cannot connect to a hostname. Network connection via IP protocol requires you to have an IP address. If you have a hostname, then you have to obtain IP address for that hostname, either via DNS or your local `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with Reverse DNS from Mysql side and host was in blocked state.

flushing of the host cache resolved the issue.
Reference :  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html